# Bubbling up div width in nested divs

Tags: html, css

How can I cause a parent div to grow according to the size of nested div?

e.g.
I have three nested divs and I need the grand-parent div to have `min-height:80px` and let it grow until`max-height:120px`- as the grand-children text grows...

Please look at the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EB3SU/7/)

p.s. I'm using Firefox.

Comment: First you should ask yourself if that approach is necessary. Why do you need that type of behavior?

Comment: I'm assuming that `div#dynamictext` must be positioned absolutely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `position:absolute;` for your `#dynamictext`

In this update of your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EB3SU/9/

I changed it to `position:relative;` and it worked fine.